# workbook.Save() throwing TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Tags: python, excel, vba, win32com

I am trying to run an excel macro via python (v2.7). The macro function runs fine, but when I try to save the workbook, it errors out saying `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable`.

Here is the relevant code:

```
def run_vba(xlpath, fn):
    xlapp = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    wbook = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(xlpath)
    parent, xl = os.path.split(xlpath)
    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.info("Running fn %s at %s" % (fn, xl))
    xlapp.run("'%s'!%s" % (xl, fn))
    log.info('Ran macro, now saving...')
    wbook.Save() # <--- fails here
    log.info('Saved, now closing...')
    wbook.Close()
    xlapp.quit()
```

I am new to windows programming in python, so would like some help on this error and how to debug and root cause.

Comment: It sounds like `xlapp.Workbooks.Open(xlpath)` returns a boolean indicating if the file opened or not. I don't know the API, but maybe you mean `xlapp.Save()`?

Comment: unfortunately, this tip didn't help. i double-checked and it is indeed wbook.Save() according to the api. see examples at http://pythonexcels.com/python-excel-mini-cookbook/.

Comment: Obvious question maybe but is the workbook referenced by `wbook` still open? You can also try doing the save as part of the close `wbook.Close(True)`

Comment: It finally worked! I started by keeping `time.sleep(20)` between each of the `wbook.*` calls. The script then succeeded a few times, but still kept failing now and then. I then discovered that the workbook had quite a few data connections, and for each of them, 'refresh data when opening the file' was checked. Removed that condition and reran - it worked serenely. Rude excel learnings :-) Thanks for the `wbook.Close(True)` tip btw!